# Calendar not sending acceptance notifications to meeting organisers (ICS invites)

Tags: iphone, mac, mail.app, calendar, ical

I am working with iCloud, iPhone and Macbook Pro on Yosemite.

I receive ICS calendar invites via mail from a user using Outlook. When I click on the ICS file in the mail, it opens and I can add it to my calendar without a problem. It also syncs nicely on all my devices.

However, the sender of the invite does not get a confirmation, in the meeting properties I'm shown as "did not reply". When I open the invite in my calendar, I have no option to accept or send a notification.

In short: ICS invites are added to my calendar but the organizer does not receive a notification.

How can I send an accept notification?

Comment: is that a google calendar ?

Comment: No - it is the stock Apple Calendar App on OS X and iOS together with an iCloud mail/calendar account

Answer (score 0):

Open the Contacts app, select your own email address in the list of contacts. In the menu on top of the screen, go to "Card" -> "Make this my card". Reload calendar. Then it should work, you will get a notification popup with accept/decline buttons. (I just had the same problem, on a Mac running Yosemite)
[Source](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5498622)